# Extract data from MySQL using Node.js and display on HTML page

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to extract data from MySQL and display it on my HTML page, but when I run the code below on my browser `http://localhost:3000`, the data does not display on my page. I would appreciate if somebody could help me solve this problem.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data from MySQL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output_message"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mywebsite"
});

connection.connect();

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM chat",(err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err); 
            res.json({"error":true});
        }
        else { 
            console.log(result); 
            res.json(result); 
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Connected to port 3000');
});
```

Comment: can you tell us if you get any error in the console?

Comment: I've got no errors in the console

Comment: well the reason is because you are sending an empty html file through GET method

Comment: How do I send it to my html file?

Comment: include the POST method logic in the GET method, and remove the post

Comment: Where do I put this code `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");`

Comment: You wont need that. I will write a more detailed answer in a min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple factors you need to consider :

1 - When you want to use a POST method sent through a HTML file you must have a

```
<form action="Name of your processing file" method="POST">YOUR FORM HERE</form>
```

However; if you simply trying to call a db and get your data then just perform

your logic within the GET method as following:

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
        else {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM chat",(err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err); 
                    res.json({"error":true});
                }
                else { 
                    console.log(result); 
                    res.json(result); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

*** You may ask what about the index.html . There are two responses for that :

1 - Use `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/YOURPAGE-Name.html");` when you want to send a file

as a result

Example:

```
app.get("/",(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Welcome.html");
});
```

Welcome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data from MySQL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Welcome to my page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

2 - Use `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");` when you want to get the

initial page so then you can have forms within the application that you want to process

Example:

```
app.get("/",(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data from MySQL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
          //YOUR FORM HERE 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The data still doesn't display on my html page. I haven't got any errors either. I've edited my code so you can see what I have changed.

Comment: remove the first GET method. You only need the second get method to get the data from db and display it

Comment: I've removed it, but I'm still not getting the data. I've only got the second get method.

Comment: modify this and lets see if you can even connect to db....      connection.connect(function(err){if(err) throw err; console.log("connected");

Comment: It says "connected" on the server response

Comment: ok good. I think i know where the prob is. Let me modify the answer

Comment: The code layout for the else statement is incorrect. I get a unexpected token message on the server response