# How to display data from MySQL into HTML-Page with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I'm new in Node JS and I'm trying to display the fetched data from my MySQL Table into a table in my HTML-File. But I couldn't find anything that helped me. I would really appreciate it if somebody can help me to get a solution! :) 
Here's my js-code:

```js
//app.js
// Get the mysql service
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (request , response) {
    fetchData(response);
    console.log('Done. Displayed Data.');

});
// Add the credentials to access your database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'Breunninger',
    port: '3306'
});
// connect to mysql
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err){throw err;}
    console.log('Connected');
});

function executeQuery(sql, cb){
    connection.query(sql, function( result, fields){

        cb(result);
    })

}

function fetchData(response){
    executeQuery("SELECT username, tor, datum, sendungsstruktur FROM Buchung JOIN user ON(user.id = Buchung.userid)", function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        response.write('<div class="container-wrap"><table id="example" class="display"><tr>');
        for(var column in result[0]){
            response.write('<td> <label>' + column + '</label></td>');
            response.write('</tr>');
        }
        for(var row in result){
            response.write('<tr>');
            for(var column in result[row]){
                response.write('<td>' + result[row][column]+ '</td>');
            }
            response.write('</tr>');
        }
        response.end('</table></div>');
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What from your example is not working? Could you please run your code and provide example output.

Comment: I don't get errors or something else. the console just displays that the database is connected. But I also want to see the result in the console AND I want to display the result in a HTML File (But I don't know how and I also couldn't find anything in the www) @Max

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract data from MySQL using Node.js and display on HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201943/extract-data-from-mysql-using-node-js-and-display-on-html-page)

Comment: Also, you are using express and `response` doesn't have `write` function. `executeQuery`'s callback should have params like this `(error, results, fields)`. Did you check the value of `error`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small (but critical!) error in the executeQuery function, the first argument should be the error object, so if you can re-write this as below your query should work.

```
function executeQuery(sql, cb){
    connection.query(sql, function( error, result, fields){
        if (error) {
            console.error("An error has occurred:", error);
        } else {
            cb(result);
        }   
    })
}
```

Node callback usually reserve the first argument for an error object, it's easy to miss this!

Also, we should be clear, the Node.js Express code will be running on the server side, so to see the results you need to point your browser to the host and port this is serving, e.g. http://localhost:3000/ (if you do:)

```
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried it with the new executeQuery function but the data still doesn't show up in my console.
Which port should I use? the port from the Apache Server or my Database? If I use the Port from the database I get the EADDRINUSE..

Comment: You should be able to use any port other than the database port, or the Apache Server. Common port numbers (for development purposes) would be 3000, 8000, 8080. Give those a try! Remember your browser address will be: http://localhost:port/, e.g. http://localhost:3000. (I'm assuming that you are running it locally!)

Comment: Okay, I used another port now. But the result still doesn't display in my console :( 
I'm really sorry for asking such dumb questions but I'm still in learning :-D

Comment: No such thing as a dumb question. We're all learning all the time! So you're running node and then connecting your browser to your node instance? The code will only run when a request is received by the Express server!

Comment: No I'm just starting the node app to check if the result shows up in my console

Comment: Ok, cool, the problem is that the query won't be run unless you get a request from a browser or maybe curl. You could try running curl http://localhost:<port>/ as well to make a request!